# Download error IBM CPlex Student version

Tags: download, cplex

[university not registered in ibm database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhBQQ.png)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an issue between your University and IBM.  It is not a programming problem.

Comment: Hint: talk to your lecturer, or someone in your university's administration to get the domain registered with IBM.